# h20.deeplearning in R error: not found for argument: key

Tags: r, deep-learning, h2o

I have a problem with h2o (deeplearning) in RStudio. 
It's the first time I'm using h2o and everytime I try to get a model with h2o.deeplearning() the prozess freezes when it reaches 100%. And when I want to build multiple models in a loop (as added below) it reaches 100% for the first model an then freezes. 
I attach my code and the error message below:

```
 <<>>= remove/install packages
# The following two commands remove any previously installed H2O packages     for R.
if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) { detach("package:h2o", unload=TRUE) }
if ("h2o" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) { remove.packages("h2o") }

# Next, we download packages that H2O depends on.
pkgs <- c("methods","statmod","stats","graphics","RCurl","jsonlite","tools","utils")
for (pkg in pkgs) {
if (! (pkg %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages(pkg) }
}

# Now we download, install and initialize the H2O package for R.
install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos=(c("http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-tverberg/5/R")))
@
<<>>==

library(h2o)
localH2O=h2o.init(nthreads = -1)
@
```

[I get this result after init(nthreads=-1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JM4iG.png)

```
<<>>= #load data
training <- read.csv("training.csv", row.names = "ID", colClasses = c(Affection = "factor"))
testing <- read.csv("testing.csv", row.names = "ID", colClasses = c(DRB1_1 = "factor"))
training_h2o <- as.h2o(training)
testing_h2o <- as.h2o(testing)
@
```

I then try to build multiple models similar to the explanation here: [githup explanation](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-training-book/blob/master/hands-on_training/deep_learning.md)

```
<<>>=#tune Parameter

#compute multiple models
models <- c()
for (i in 1:5){
rand_activation <- c("Tanh", "Rectifier")[sample(1:2,1)]
rand_epochs <- sample(c(10, 15),1)
rand_hidden <- c(sample(100:500,2))
rand_l1 <- runif(1, 0, 1e-3)
rand_l2 <- runif(1, 0, 1e-3)
rand_input_dropout <- runif(1, 0, 0.5)
dl.model <- h2o.deeplearning(x = 2:3979, y = 1, training_frame =  training_h2o, nfolds = 10, keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,   variable_importances = TRUE, adaptive_rate = TRUE,
 activation = rand_activation, hidden = rand_hidden, l1=rand_l1, l2 =     rand_l2, epochs = rand_epochs, input_dropout_ratio = rand_input_dropout)  
models <- c(models, dl.model)
}
```

But as mentioned before this always freezes and when I cancel it I get the following error (shortened):

```
ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 404 Not Found (url =   http://localhost:54321/3/Models/DeepLearning_model_R_1488120350711_1)

water.exceptions.H2OKeyNotFoundArgumentException
[1] "water.exceptions.H2OKeyNotFoundArgumentException: Object    'DeepLearning_model_R_1488120350711_1' not found for argument: key"
 [2] "    water.api.ModelsHandler.getFromDKV(ModelsHandler.java:110)"                                                             
 [3] "    water.api.ModelsHandler.fetch(ModelsHandler.java:129)"                                                                  
 [4] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"                                                            
 [5] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)"                                                            

[35] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)"                                       
[36] "        org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)"                                        
[37] "    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"                                                                                   

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix =    page,  : 


ERROR MESSAGE:

Object 'DeepLearning_model_R_1488120350711_1' not found for argument: key
```

Can someone help me with this? I never used h2o before and am not sure I used the commands correctly but tried to stay close to the h2o.pdf. 
I also can't open the url given in the error.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How did you create the training frame, `training_h2o`?  My first guess is that it's a regular R data.frame and not an H2O Frame.

Comment: Also, that h2o-training-book repository is 3 years old and is based on H2O 2.0.  The R API to H2O changed slightly when we released H2O 3.0, and one of the things that changed was how you train a grid of models (I'll make sure we note that in the repo).  If you are trying to train a deep learning grid, I'd recommend looking here for an example instead: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/h2o-open-tour-2016/chicago/grid-search-model-selection.R#L182

Comment: @ErinLeDell I experienced a similar error with H2o 3.8 and it brings `ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 400 Bad Request (url = http://localhost:54321/3/ModelBuilders/deeplearning)` I used R 4.1.3.  This was working perfectly okay before. In fact, I created my autoencoder model successfully but it started failing when I edited model_id to a readable name. Even when I returned the initial name back it keeps giving the same error

Comment: Hi there, are you sure you mean 3.8?  H2O v. 3.8 is 7 years old so if you're encountering bugs, I would recommend updating H2O.